# Dados de formulário PHP não entram no banco

Tags: php, mysql, sql, formulário

Olá, sou novato em PHP e tô fazendo uma pequena página de agendamento mas emperrei na parte de inserção dos dados dentro do banco, abaixo meus códigos:

Index.php

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title> Controle de Coleta </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="include/estilo.css"/>
  </head>
  <body>
<?php include("include/db.php") ?>
<form action="include/verifica.php" method="POST">
<pre>
Insira as informações da coleta:
<table width="100%" class="tabela2">
<thead bgcolor="#D1DCEB"><tr>
<th>Data da Coleta</th>
<th>Hora da Coleta</th>
<th>Unidade</th>
<th>Observação</th>
<th>Solicitante</th>
<th>Coletadora</th>
<th>Cadastrar</th>
</tr></thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><input type="text" size="27" maxlenght="256" name="data_chamada"></td>
<td><input type="text" size="27" maxlenght="256" name="hora_coleta"></td>
<td><input type="text" size="27" maxlenght="256" name="unidade"></td>
<td><input type="text" size="26" maxlenght="256" name="observacao"></td>
<td><input type="text" size="26" maxlenght="256" name="solicitante"></td>
<td><input type="text" size="26" maxlenght="256" name="coletadora"></td>
<td><input type="submit" value="Cadastrar" name="enviar"></td>
</tr>
</pre>
</form>
<?php
echo '<table width="100%" class="tabela1">';
echo '<thead bgcolor="#D1DCEB"><tr>';
echo '<th><font size="2" color="#336699">Data Chamada</th>';
//echo '<th><font size="2" color="#336699">Hora Chamada</th>';
echo '<th><font size="2" color="#336699">Unidade</th>';
echo '<th><font size="2" color="#336699">Observação</th>';
echo '<th><font size="2" color="#336699">Solicitante</th>';
echo '<th><font size="2" color="#336699">Coletadora</th>';
echo '<th><font size="2" color="#336699">Hora Coleta</th>';
echo '<th><font size="2" color="#336699">Protocolo</th>';
echo '</tr></thead>';
echo '<tbody>';

$sql = mysql_query('SELECT *, date_format(data_chamada, "%d%/%m%/%Y") as data_chamada FROM coleta_hc_2017 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 100;');
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
   echo '<tr>';
   echo '<td><font size="2">' . $row['data_chamada'] . '</td>';
//   echo '<td><font size="2">' . $row['hora_chamada'] . '</td>';
   echo '<td><font size="2">' . $row['unidade'] . '</td>';
   echo '<td><font size="2">' . $row['observacao'] . '</td>';
   echo '<td><font size="2">' . $row['solicitante'] . '</td>';
   echo '<td><font size="2">' . $row['coletadora'] . '</td>';
   echo '<td><font size="2">' . $row['hora_coleta'] . '</td>';
   echo '<td><font size="2">' . $row['id'] . '</td>';
   echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</tbody></table>';
?>
</body>
</html>
```

include/db.php

```
<?php
$servidor = "ipserver";
$usuario = "usrteste";
$banco = "minhadb";
$senha = "pwteste";
//Não Alterar abaixo:
$conmysql = mysql_connect($servidor,$usuario,$senha);
$db = mysql_select_db($banco, $conmysql);
if ($conmysql && $db){
echo "Parabens! A conexão ao banco de dados ocorreu normalmente!";
} else {
echo "Nao foi possivel conectar ao banco MYSQL";
}
?>
```

include/verifica.php

```html
<html>
<body>
<?php
$data_chamada = $_POST["data_chamada"];
//$hora_chamada = $_POST["hora_chamada"];
$hora_coleta  = $_POST["hora_coleta"];
$unidade      = $_POST["unidade"];
$observacao   = $_POST["observacao"];
$solicitante  = $_POST["solicitante"];
$coletadora   = $_POST["coletadora"];
$erro         = 0;

// Verifica se os campos não estão em branco
if (empty($data_chamada))
  {echo "Favor inserir a Data da Chamada.<br>"; $erro=1;}
if (empty($hora_coleta))
  {echo "Favor inserir a Hora da Coleta.<br>"; $erro=1;}
if (empty($unidade))
  {echo "Favor inserir a Unidade.<br>"; $erro=1;}
if (empty($observacao))
  {echo "Favor inserir a Observação.<br>"; $erro=1;}
if (empty($solicitante))
  {echo "Favor inserir o Solicitante.<br>"; $erro=1;}
if (empty($coletadora))
  {echo "Favor inserir a Coletadora.<br>"; $erro=1;}
//Verifica se não houve erro
if($erro==0)
  {echo "Todos os dados foram inseridos corretamente!";
  include 'insere.php';
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

include/insere.php

```
<?php

include 'db.php';

$data_chamada = $_POST['data_chamada'];
$hora_chamada = date("H:i:s");
$hora_coleta  = $_POST['hora_coleta'];
$unidade      = $_POST['unidade'];
$observacao   = $_POST['observacao'];
$solicitante  = $_POST['solicitante'];
$coletadora   = $_POST['coletadora'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO minhatable VALUES";
$sql = "('$data_chamada', '$hora_chamada', '$hora_coleta', '$unidade', '$observacao', '$solicitante', '$coletadora')";
?>
```

Não consigo identificar onde exatamente está o problema, pelo que vi é no passo final, ele verifica(verifica.php) os dados mas não insere(insere.php).

PS1 : Tem duas coisas que não sei se estão corretas, uma delas é que precisava que a coluna "hora_chamada" guardasse o horário do servidor no momento em que foi realizado o cadastro, fiz da maneira correta(olhar no insere.php)?

PS2: Tenho uma coluna chamada "id", precisava que em todo novo cadastro ela contasse +1.

Obrigado desde já!

Comment: Seu código não chama nenhuma função que faça inserção no DB. Então não vai mesmo inserir. Fica a sugestão de ler ao menos o manual do PHP e pegar exemplos básicos.

Comment: Além do que o @Bacco já disse. A ultima linha do `insere.php` deveria ser `$sql += " ('$data_chamada', '$hora_chamada', '$hora_coleta', '$unidade', '$observacao', '$solicitante', '$coletadora')";`

Comment: Aproveitando o embalo, sugiro também uma [pesquisa por SQL Injection aqui no site](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=sql+injection). Se usar o código da forma que está (resolvendo a parte da inserção) está dando acesso praticamente irrestrito ao seu DB pelo formulário.

Comment: Eu resolvi o problema do insere.php, agora está guardando os dados tudo ok, mas a questão do SQL Injection me pegou agora, o sistema vai ser usado apenas internamente na empresa, não é absolutamente assustador, mas é bom aprender, tem algo em específico deixando o sistema inseguro ou é uma soma de muitas coisas?